# Computing $\mathbb{E}[X_1S^4]$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$. If we are given $S=\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i$ and the fact that $\mathbb{E}[S^5]=30$ what method do you need to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_1S^4]$? I don't know how to start with the general idea of expectation and iid rvs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the linearity of the expectation and the fact that the distribution of $X_i S^4$ is the same for all $i$.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[S^5]=\mathbb{E}[\sum _{i=1}^{10}X_iS^4]=\sum _{i=1}^{10}\mathbb{E}[X_iS^4]=\sum _{i=1}^{10}\mathbb{E}[X_1S^4]=10\mathbb{E}[X_1S^4]=30$

Comment: Why not ask your school professor on to the forum to help out answering your long list of homework exercises?